# eclipse UI black-ness ... not just yet

Tags: eclipse, themes, ubuntu-10.10

If you look at the screenshot below, I managed to do 99% of it, except the ugly white border around the minimised side window.

Any idea how to remove that?

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 with a customised (colours and icons) theme based on ClearLookClassic.

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is seems to be a bug with eclipse.
I have [bugged it](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=336911) with eclipse.org